# Complex Left Join with Variables

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

Having a bit of an issue with LEFT JOIN in a Mysqli statement. I have two tables, one that has single entries for various events. The second table has all the images for that event.

**What I want to get:** I want to get a single return for the last 8 events with an image count for that event and the last image uploaded for the event.

**The problem:** A simple LEFT JOIN would be great for this, however that's a hitch... sometimes there's multiple days for these events. So the one thing that connects the two tables together is the FOLDER field. But, the can also differ if there's more than one day. This makes match up the event to the images a bit tougher.

**Visual example:**

***Table: Events***

```
Title      Folder          Days    Added
-------------------------------------------
Event1     2015-EventA     1       20151001
Event2     2015-EventB     2       20150901
Event3     2015-EventC     3       20150801
```

***Table: Images***

```
File         Folder             Date
---------------------------------------
imgA1.jpg    2015-EventA        20150930
imgA2.jpg    2015-EventA        20151001
imgB1.jpg    2015-EventB-1      20150910
imgB2.jpg    2015-EventB-2      20150901
imgC1.jpg    2015-EventC-1      20150910
imgC2.jpg    2015-EventC-2      20151001
imgC3.jpg    2015-EventC-2      20150930
imgC4.jpg    2015-EventC-3      20150927
```

**Result I'm looking for (remember it's picking the last uploaded image for that event):**

```
Title      Folder          Days     File         IMGCount     IMGFolder
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Event 1    2015-EventA     1        imgA2.jpg    2            2015-EventA
Event 2    2015-EventB     2        imgB1.jpg    2            2015-EventB-1 
Event 3    2015-EventC     3        imgC2.jpg    4            2015-EventC-2
```

**What I've tried:**

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.IMGCount, t2.File, T2.Folder AS IMGFolder
 FROM Events as t1
 LEFT JOIN (select count(File) AS IMGCount, Folder, File
         FROM Images GROUP BY Folder ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 8)
AS t2
on t1.Folder LIKE t2.Folder
OR t1.Folder LIKE t2.Folder || '-1'
OR t1.Folder LIKE t2.Folder || '-2'
OR t1.Folder LIKE t2.Folder || '-3'
OR t1.Folder LIKE t2.Folder || '-4'
   ORDER BY Added DESC LIMIT 8
```

This ALMOST works... but the Event table repeats the first Event's information for all the matches... so I get this which has correct Image table info, but repeated Event:

```
Title      Folder          Days     File         IMGCount     IMGFolder
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Event 1    2015-EventA     1        imgA2.jpg    2            2015-EventA
Event 1    2015-EventA     1        imgB1.jpg    2            2015-EventB-1 
Event 1    2015-EventA     1        imgC2.jpg    4            2015-EventC-2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I assume DATE is string?

Comment: Yes, for Date and Added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really, you should fix your data structure.  You need proper keys connecting the tables (such as an event id).

But, you can do what you want by aggregating `images` to get the count and maximum date and then joining back to `images`:

```
SELECT e.*, t2.IMGCount, t2.File, T2.Folder AS IMGFolder
FROM Events e JOIN
     (select count(File) AS IMGCount,
             substring_index(Folder, '-', 2) as efolder, MAX(date) as maxdate
      from Images
      GROUP BY eFolder
      ORDER BY maxdate DESC
      LIMIT 8
     ) i
     ON i.efolder = e.folder JOIN
     images ii
     ON substring_index(ii.Folder, '-', 2) = e.folder and
        ii.date = i.maxdate;
```

Comment: I'm getting an error when I run this: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'images ii ON substring_index(ii.Folder, '-', 2) = e.folder and ' at line 11

Answer (score 1):

1. This wasn't easy. First select give you total of images.
2. Second give you what is the latest date picture for each event.
3. Last give you what is that image.

**[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd9013/31)**

```
SELECT imgC.*, imgFile.`File`
FROM 
    (
      SELECT E.`Folder`, E.`Title`, E.`Days`, COUNT(I.`File`) as IMGCount
      FROM Events E
      JOIN Images I
       ON E.`Folder` = SUBSTRING(I.`Folder`, 1,11)
      GROUP BY E.`Folder`, E.`Title`, E.`Days`
    ) as imgC 
JOIN 
    (
      SELECT E.`Folder`,  MAX(`Date`) as `LastDate`
      FROM Events E
      JOIN Images I
        ON E.`Folder` = SUBSTRING(I.`Folder`, 1,11)
      GROUP BY E.`Folder`
    ) as imgDate
ON imgC.`Folder` = imgDate.`Folder`
JOIN (
        SELECT E.`Folder`,  I.`File`, I.`Date`
        FROM Events E
        JOIN Images I
          ON E.`Folder` = SUBSTRING(I.`Folder`, 1,11)
      ) as imgFile
ON imgDate.`Folder` = imgFile.`Folder`
and imgDate.`LastDate` = imgFile.`Date`
```

Comment: I ran this code, but for some reason for me it brought up tons and tons and tons of images. Example: `folder event days   IMGCount File
2009-Hemet Hemet-Ryan Airshow 1 27 HemetRyan09_B-25J_Mitchell_3909.jpg
2009-Hemet Hemet-Ryan Airshow 1 27 HemetRyan09_B-25J_Mitchell_4024.jpg
2009-Hemet Hemet-Ryan Airshow 1 27 HemetRyan09_B-25J_Mitchell_6587.jpg
2009-Hemet Hemet-Ryan Airshow 1 27 HemetRyan09_C-53D_Skytrooper_3875.jpg
2009-Hemet Hemet-Ryan Airshow 1 27 HemetRyan09_Dr_D_Taylorcraft_4207.jpg
2009-Hemet Hemet-Ryan Airshow 1 27 HemetRyan09_EH-1H_Huey_5215.jpg`

Comment: Yikes, the comments don't handle code well do they?

Comment: Yes you should put your comment in your questions as additional info Or even better just update my SqlFiddle recreate the schema and send me the link. Btw very cool picture on your profile. Getting jelous :)

Comment: Now I see what are you picture about. `Air shows` now more Jelous. Dont know why the photographer is doing the db, but you should listen Gordon, you should improve the db design to make thing easy in the future.

Comment: Sorry, have been out of town at airshows! I ended up using a combination of your answer and Gordon's to get what I need. How can I award you both as answers?

Comment: You should go with Gordon, his answer is better than mine. :) And not the first time I learn something from him.